# What is "std::vector<unsigned char> Data = example"?

Tags: c++

```
std::vector<unsigned char> Data = example
```

I found this on the internet somewhere and I think it writes an array of bytes of unknown size to a given address but I'm not entirely sure. Can anyone explain what this does?

And if this doesn't do what I think it does can someone help me produce a C++ function that takes an address and bytes as arguments and writes them at that address ie:

```
myfunction(0xaddress, {0x10, 0x11, 0x12}); // something like this
```

Comment: Do you mean `std::vector<unsigned char> Data = "example";`

Comment: That's exactly what I was given, sorry can't help you more I'm no good at this memory writing business :( I added more to the first post.

Comment: with regards to your last question, can you rewrite your function argument as `"\x10\x11\x12"` or is that out of the question?

Comment: @MrLister Yes I can do that! :)

Comment: @MrLister but you have to remember that it could be any size ie: 1 byte or 20 bytes.

Comment: @kvanberendonck Yes, but the trick is that you know the length now, and you can simply copy the bytes over. But you need to be able to copy bytes with value 0 too, I guess? I overlooked that.

Comment: @MrLister whats the problem with 0 values? The bytes I copy will always be entered beforehand, never in realtime so I know the values before I copy them; they will be declared at the top of my code.

Comment: @kvanberendonck I expanded my comment a bit. See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write an x amount of bytes to an address, you have a number of options.

```
void myfunction(void* address, size_t count, const unsigned char data[])
{..}

const unsigned char bytes[] = {0x10, 0x11, 0x12};
myfunction (address, 3, bytes);
```

where the second argument, count, is the length of the array.
Or with a variadic function:

```
void myfunction(void* address, size_t count, ...)
{..}

myfunction (address, 3, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12);
```

In all cases, you'll need to give the byte count explicitly though; the compiler can't deduce that from the data.

If you want to use a vector, that's possible, but you'll need to populate the vector first before calling the function, which isn't as efficient.

The only case where you wouldn't need to provide the count yourself is if none of the bytes would have value 0, then you could write

```
void myfunction(void* address, const char* str)
{..}

myfunction (address, "\x10\x11\x12");
```

because you could use strlen!

Edit:
Also, `std::basic_string<unsigned char>` would be worth looking into. But here too, it's not trivial to give this a value that contains `\x00` values.

Answer (score 2):

The = operator of a vector will copy the contents of the rvalue (assuming rvalue is of type vector with the same type or a class which implements a casting to a vector from this same type).

No address is being copied here only the contents.

Comment: How do you know it's an rvalue?  One of the few things we can guess about "example" is that it's probably an lvalue.

Comment: In actual fact if it was a rvalue then this answer would be wrong on a modern compiler because that rvalue would be moved into the vector either using move semantics or elision.

Comment: in this particular case example I assumed it is

Comment: Can you answer the second question with a snippet, maybe accepting a string argument like MrLister suggested above.

Comment: I think MrListener did quite a good job. Doess his answer not good enough ? or you mean implementation for the function ?

Comment: Posted that before Mr Lister gave his brilliant answer :)